# Android Animations on Percent Library

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation, android-percent-library

I have been researching the topic of animations on Android but have come against a brick wall when it comes to implementing these findings against a project that utilises the Percent library.

In particular, I have the following element in my layout xml:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aImage"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="35%"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

With the following attribute assigned to the root `PercentRelativeLayout` element:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Now, I want to create an `AnimatorSet`object that can carry out multiple manipulations with the focus being on the `app:layout_marginTopPercent="35%"` attribute.

I have tried creating an ObjectAnimator and adding it to an AnimatorSet but this has no effect:

```
ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(logoImageView, "layout_marginTopPercent", 0.35f, 0.1f);
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playSequentially(anim1);
animatorSet.start();
```

Could anybody please explain where I am going wrong. Interestingly, I am able to create a animation .xml file and use the translate element to perform a successful animation but I need to do this in code. Below is an example of the successful .XML animation:

```
<set>
        <translate
         android:fromYDelta="0%p"
         android:toYDelta="-25%p"
         android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you see anything related to `"layout_marginTopPercent"` on the logcat?

Comment: Unforunately not. The logcat is not showing anything pertinent @pskink

Comment: nothing about not implemented method? aha, set the duration for `anim1`

Comment: There must be a default animation duration because if I change the layout_marginTopPercent to 'Y' the animation works. Either way, setting the duration makes no difference.

Comment: no logcat warning about not existing method `setLayout_marginTopPercent` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new version (>=1.3.0) of my library [ViewPropertyObjectAnimator](https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator) provides a way to animate `percent` parameters from `Percent Support Library`. Obtaining an `ObjectAnimator` (which you can use inside your `AnimatorSet`) is as easy as using `ViewPropertyAnimator`.

```
ObjectAnimator logoMarginAnimator = 
            ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(logoImageView).topMarginPercent(0.1f).get();
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.play(logoMarginAnimator);
animatorSet.start();
```

Comment: Just trying out this library now but looks impressive

Comment: If you find any problems with it (especially with animating `percent` parameters), please let me know.

Comment: This is a third party selection but it is thoroughly recommended. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Glad you like it :)